# Non expiring cookie in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET core application which uses cookies to store some information which I uses to handle requests.

I want these cookies not to be expired, so I don't have to inject again. I used following code in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(99);
    options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
});
```

Injecting cookies

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Type", "Value");
```

Even If I add this code, sometimes when I restart the local IIS server or randomly without restarting the local IIS server. The cookies are cleared and I don't have access to them within HttpContext.

```
context.HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains(_claimName); //Returns null
```

How can I make sure my cookies are not getting expired?

Comment: You are not using cookies. You are using session state (which stores the information server-side, but depends on a cookie). Your issue is that the server-side memory is getting cleared, and [in process session state is notoriously unreliable in production scenarios](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/).

Comment: Long story short, you need to use a distributed session store like Redis or SQL Server. Something where the data will survive server/app restarts.